# Handling required processing unit and memory for a task

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say , we have a Spark cluster having a driver node and single worker node.

The worker node has below configuration.

- number of executors : 3
- number of cores per executors : 5 (total 15 cores in worker node)
- memory per executor : 63 GB (total at worker level) / 3 executor = 21 GB

The maximum number of parallel tasks that can run is determined by the available cores, which in this instance is 15. In typical scenarios involving large volumes of data, certain tasks may require additional processing cores or memory. Typically, each task is allocated one core.

Is there a configuration available to allocate more than one core per task and memory, if not, how does Spark manage such situations?

Comment: as far as I know, one task is executed in one core. you cannot assign a task to multiple cores. actually, that is how tasks are defined, all should be manageable by a core. In a nutshell, Spark is already dividing the jobs into multiple tasks that can be executed by each executor. You can think it like cores=tasks=slots

Comment: got it. In that case how do we (or spark) handle cases where -  In typical scenarios involving large volumes of data, certain tasks may require additional processing cores or memory?

Comment: If the volume of data is large, spark is dividing it to smaller chunks (tasks) that can be done (manageable) via memory, cores assigned to that task. If there is a problem, spark automatically re-execute that task (thanks to DAG). Otherwise, you get out of memory error.